# Asp.Net Core 2.1 Angular app does not answer request

Tags: asp.net-core

I have SPA Angular 6 app being run with asp.net core 2.1. Unpredictably, http request to the api controller will never be answered.  When I look in the browser debug, it shows the request as "pending".  So I added some middleware:

```
public static void UseRequestLogger(this IApplicationBuilder app) {

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var logger = context.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<MyLoggerService>>();
            var id = Guid.NewGuid();

            logger.LogDebug($"starting request: {context.Request.Path}-{id}");
             await next();

            logger.LogDebug($"ending request: {context.Request.Path}-{id}");

        });
    }
```

I then call `app.UseRequestLogger()` at the top of the `Configure` method of StartUp.cs.  When my request is stuck at "pending" in the browser, Ive noticed the middleware is never processed.  Im kind of at a loss on where to go from here.  If the middleware is not being hit, what comes before that and how can I check it?

Comment: What do the application logs say?

Comment: @poke nothin'....everything is normal, or it looks that way in any case.

Comment: But do those requests hit the server?

Comment: @poke as far as I can tell, no.  No log of it hitting the server, but if I kill app pool in IIS I get a 502 error, so it has to be making it to some portion of the server.

Comment: So you are running behind IIS? What do the IIS logs say then? Do any requests work? Does it work if you run your app without IIS?

Comment: @poke its the same behavior with or without IIS

Comment: I can cancel and re-issue the request, and it will go through just fine

Answer (score 0):

Same config and same unpredictable behavior for me.

Unless debug with API hosted in IIS + FireFox (bugs only with Chrome here), **or API self-hosted** (through launchSettings.json).

```
{
    ...
    "profiles": {
        "YourProjectName": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:10001"
        },
        "IIS": {
            "commandName": "IIS",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

My advise is to debug communication between your app and api self-hosted.
Then in production you may host the API under IIS, which has never caused problems in Release mode in my experience.